# pdflib table (php) alignin text to the right makes it jump up

Tags: php, pdflib

I have yet another issue with creating a PDF.

I wrote a generic function which will create a table.

```
// to set up a table one needs to supply: 
// the font detailss for 
// the header and the table body (font, fontsize, textPosition)
//
// the multidimensional array to hold info about the header
// headerText, columnWidth
// for advanced users
// extra seetings can be added to each column as a key=>value
// pair in the 'additional' array
//
// table body requires a multidimensional array that will hold
// an array of field values for every row
//
// coordinates for the lower left and upper right corners
// lowerLeftX, lowerLeftY and upperRightX, upperRightY
protected function displayTable(
    $headerFont=array('fontName'=>'', 'fontEncoding'=>'', 'fontSize'=>''), 
    $headers=array( array('headerText'=>'', 'columnWidth'=>'', 'textPosition'=>'',
                        'additional'=>array()), 
                    array('headerText'=>'', 'columnWidth'=>'', 'textPosition'=>'',
                        'additional'=>array())),
    $fieldsFont=array('fontName'=>'', 'fontEncoding'=>'', 'fontSize'=>''), 
    $fields=array(array(    
                    array('value'=>'fieldValue', 'textPosition'=>''),
                    array('value'=>'fieldValue', 'textPosition'=>'')
                    )),
    $lowerLeftX, $lowerLeftY, $upperRightX, $upperRightY,
    $tableOptions = "header=1 rowheightdefault=auto"){

    $table = 0;
    $headFont = 0;

    //generate headers
    $row = 1;
    $headFont = pdf_load_font($this->pdf, $headerFont['fontName'], $headerFont['fontEncoding'], "");

    if ($headFont == 0) {

        die("Error: " . pdf_get_errmsg($this->pdf));

    }
    $col = 0;

    foreach ($headers as $header){

        $col++;

        $optionList = "fittextline={position=".$header['textPosition']." 
                        font=" .$headFont. " 
                        fontsize=".$headerFont['fontSize']."} 
                        colwidth=".$header['columnWidth'];

        if ((isset($header['additional'])) && (!empty($header['additional']))){

            foreach ($header['additional'] as $key=>$value){

                $optionList.=" ".$key."=".$value;

            }

        }

        $table = pdf_add_table_cell($this->pdf,$table, $col, $row, $header['headerText'], $optionList);

        if ($table == 0) {

            die("Error: " . pdf_get_errmsg($this->pdf));

        }

    }

    //the rest of the fields
    $bodyFont = pdf_load_font($this->pdf, $fieldsFont['fontName'], $fieldsFont['fontEncoding'], "");
    if ($bodyFont == 0) {

        die("Error: " . pdf_get_errmsg($this->pdf));

    }

    foreach ($fields as $line){

        $row ++;
        $col = 0;

        foreach($line as $field){

            $col++;

            $optionList = "fittextline={position=".$field['textPosition']." 
                        font=" .$bodyFont. " 
                        fontsize=".$fieldsFont['fontSize']."} ";

            $table = pdf_add_table_cell($this->pdf,$table, $col, $row, $field['value'], $optionList); 

        }

        if ($table == 0) {

            die("Error: " . pdf_get_errmsg($this->pdf));

        }
    }

    // Place the table instance 

    $result = pdf_fit_table($this->pdf, $table, $lowerLeftX, $lowerLeftY, 
                $upperRightX, $upperRightY, $tableOptions);

    if ($result ==  "_error") {

        die("Couldn't place table: " . pdf_get_errmsg($pdf));

    }

     pdf_delete_table($this->pdf, $table, "");

}
```

I have made some changes since I updated the top comments but the function is rather straight forward (if you can say that about PDFLib related functions :'-( ) and generally does follow the comments

I need a text in one of the fields to be aligned to the right

When I call that function in a different class and subsequently display it on the page, the field that I set up an alignment to the right jumps slightly up and goes out of vertical alignment. I am absolutely baffled by that.

Here's the code for calling the function

```
    //set up a table
    parent::displayTable(
    $headerFont=array('fontName'=>'ZEISSFrutigerNextW1G-BoldIt', 'fontEncoding'=>'unicode',
                'fontSize'=>'9'), 
    $headers=array( array('headerText'=>'Artikelnummeb', 'columnWidth'=>60
                    , 'textPosition'=>'left', 'additional'=>array('margin'=>4)), 
                    array('headerText'=>'Artikelbezeichnung', 'columnWidth'=>230
                    , 'textPosition'=>'left', 'additional'=>array('margin'=>4)),
                    array('headerText'=>'EAN', 'columnWidth'=>70
                    , 'textPosition'=>'left', 'additional'=>array('margin'=>2)),
                    array('headerText'=>'Preis (brutto)', 'columnWidth'=>65
                    , 'textPosition'=>'left', 'additional'=>array('margin'=>0))),
    $fieldsFont=array('fontName'=>'ZEISSFrutigerNextW1G-Light', 'fontEncoding'=>'unicode', 
                'fontSize'=>'9'), 
    $fields=array(  array(array('value'=>'01234567890123', 'textPosition'=>'left'), 
                        array('value'=>'fieldValue', 'textPosition'=>'left'), 
                        array('value'=>'8888888888888', 'textPosition'=>'left'), 
                        array('value'=>'99999.99 Eur', 'textPosition'=>'right')),


                    array(array('value'=>'01234567890123', 'textPosition'=>'left'), 
                        array('value'=>'fieldValue', 'textPosition'=>'left'), 
                        array('value'=>'8888888888888', 'textPosition'=>'left'), 
                        array('value'=>'99999.99 Eur', 'textPosition'=>'right')),

                    array(array('value'=>'01234567890123', 'textPosition'=>'left'), 
                        array('value'=>'fieldValue', 'textPosition'=>'left'), 
                        array('value'=>'8888888888888', 'textPosition'=>'left'), 
                        array('value'=>'99999.99 Eur', 'textPosition'=>'right')),

                    array(array('value'=>'01234567890123', 'textPosition'=>'left'), 
                        array('value'=>'fieldValue', 'textPosition'=>'left'), 
                        array('value'=>'8888888888888', 'textPosition'=>'left'), 
                        array('value'=>'99999.99 Eur', 'textPosition'=>'right'))),
    111, 50, 551, 400,
    $tableOptions = "header=1 rowheightdefault=auto ");
```

The result is as follows

[image: crucked table]

any ideas on ways to fix this will be welcomed

P.S. I'm sure I'm just missing something laughable, but those are the worst ones to find :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `position` option has one or two values. From the PDFlib API Reference, chapter 6.1, table 6.1:

> The keywords left, center, right (in x direction) or bottom, center, top (in y direction) can be used as
>   equivalents for the values 0, 50, and 100. If only one keyword has been specified, the corresponding keyword
>   for the other direction will be added.

In your code, you set:

```
       $optionList = "fittextline={position=".$field['textPosition']." 
                    font=" .$bodyFont. " 
                    fontsize=".$fieldsFont['fontSize']."} ";
```

which means, you apply only a single value. When you apply `right` (means 100) you get the same value as `position={right 100}` which means upper right corner.

In your case, I would recommend to extend the code to:

```
       $optionList = "fittextline={position={".$field['textPosition']." bottom}  
                    font=" .$bodyFont. " 
                    fontsize=".$fieldsFont['fontSize']."} ";
```

so you get `right bottom` similar to the `left bottom` as the default.

Comment: Not something they explained too clearly in their documentation.

Thanks for such a clear explanation :-)

I guess since you are in Munchen I could offer to buy you a drink :-)